# Calling a Codeigniter controller from cronjob

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, cron, cpanel

I have created a cron job from cpanel. The command is

```
php /home/userdir/www/index.php Messages test
```

The controller Messages and the method test just inserts a record in a temporary table.

When I run the following from command prompt on my laptop running windows, it runs fine.

```
php c:/wamp/www/project/index.php Messages test
```

This works perfectly.

However, on the hosted server running Linux, I get a mail from the server which has the html for the home page. It does not even go to the Messages->test method.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

php index.php welcome show

as command in your crontab. E.g.:

0 * * * * php /home/userdir/www/index.php Messages test

or

0 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/userdir/www/index.php Messages test

or

0 * * * * wget http://domain.com/Messages/test

http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/cli.html

Comment: the first one does not work. I have also configured a notification so in that, I can see that the html of the mainpage which would come up if you just access http://domain.com.